# A string goal with actionlib

Tags: ros, action, actionlib, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm just starting out with ROS actions. The [example](http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib) uses the goal type `uint32`, but I wanted to use a `std_msgs::String`. This is my action file:

```
# Define the goal
string sequence_name  # Name the sequence to run, e.g. "turn handle clockwise"
---
# Define the result (typically an incremental result, but just boolean in this case)
bool in_progress
---
# Define a feedback message
bool success
```

Although I stated "string" for the goal, it looks like the goal message compiles as an `unsigned int` type. Passing an `int` argument like this compiles successfully:

```
temoto::PreplannedSequenceGoal goal;
goal.sequence_name = 1;
preplanned_sequence_client_.waitForServer();
preplanned_sequence_client_.sendGoal(goal);
```

Whereas passing a std_msgs::String does not compile (type mismatch).

So, in short, can I use datatypes other than `uint32` and `float32` for the Action message components?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266734/a-string-goal-with-actionlib/) by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2331 on 2017-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-07-18**:
Actually, here's the autogenerated msg file. It is a uint32, not a string, so I guess uint32 is the only option.

```
# ====== DO NOT MODIFY! AUTOGENERATED FROM AN ACTION DEFINITION ======
# Define the goal
uint32 sequence_name  # Name the sequence to run, e.g. "turn handle clockwise"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`std_msgs/String` is different the `string` type that you used when defining the action. I would imagine that if you did:

```
goal.sequence_name = "string";
```

it would probably also work.

Additionally, if you want the type to be `std_msgs/String`, you would have to do this in your action file:

```
# Define the goal
std_msgs/String sequence_name  # Name the sequence to run, e.g. "turn handle clockwise"
---
# Define the result (typically an incremental result, but just boolean in this case)
bool in_progress
---
# Define a feedback message
bool success
```

---

Originally posted by [velveteenrobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/6196/velveteenrobot/) with karma: 136 on 2017-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-07-18**:
Eventually I found out-- you are right... There was an older Action file that never got deleted, so changing the new Action file didn't have any effect.